# How to change only params of route in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a method `add()` on component that is called in this route: `'model/:id'`.
Now, i want to add a new model, and for do this, need change the route to: `'model/0'`;

```js
add(){
    this.route.navigate(['model','0']);
}
```

> I need to do this with the 'model' route dynamically, because the
>   route can change, it's possible ?

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor import `ActivatedRoute`

```
construction(private route: ActivatedRoute, ...) {}
add() {
  this.router.navigate(['../', '0'], {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.route.navigate(['model/0']);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way

```
  this.router.navigate(['/model', 0]);
```

For more information refer [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#navigate-to-hero-detail-imperatively)